# Nginx & PHP-FPM - Unable to open primary script ERROR

Tags: nginx, rewrite, php-fpm

I have a blog with some rewrite rules when in comes to viewing single posts. The viewing is handled by a file named view.php. I am using some rewrite rules in my vhost config as follows:

```
location /view {
  rewrite ^/view/([^/.]+)?/?(.*) /view1.php?pid=$1&$query_string;
}
```

This makes the URL look like this:

```
http://domain.com/view/xxxx
```

where xxxx is the post ID. On that same page I have a social share plugin which includes a file named share.php located in the same directory as the view.php file. The plugin works fine, however I am receiving the following error in my log:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/domain.com/view/xxxx/share.php (No such file or directory)"
```

I am guessing it has something to do with the above rewrite rule in my nginx configuration file. How can I resolve this? Should I add a specific rewrite rule for the share.php file in my vhost configuration file?

Here is my php conf:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
root   /var/www/domain.com;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The important parameter here is the SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter.
you can change that line to
$document_root/share.php
or, if you want,
/var/www/domain.com/share.php
The $fastcgi_script_name is using the requestm location as the path

Regards

Comment: This would render all other php files in my domain's folder inaccessible/not-working.